# Raspberry Pi 2 B Tkinter performance problem

Tags: pi-2, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple python program for a Rasperry Pi 2 Model B. When finished it should be able to get a few values via uart and display one out of 200 images based on that.
Additionally, it will show a video and a few static images. For that, I use Tkinter and Tkvideo.
But now I run in to serious performance problems. I thought this is a simple Project and would work. But the Raspberry has trouble, even if I only start VS Code on it, and the text input has a delay of over a second.

As OS, I use ([Raspberry Pi OS with desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/)), the python version is 3.9

I reduced the Code, so it only opens a window and plays the one video:
Even if I only show the video, it renders in ca. 1-2 fps.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
       self.timeStartMS = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

       self.root = Tk()
       self.root.geometry("1280x800")

       label3 = Label(self.root, width=200, height=800, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
       label3.place(x=420,y=0)
       label3v = Label(label3)
       label3v.place(x=200,y=100)

       player = tkvideo("Video/testVideo.mp4", label3v ,loop=1)
       player.play()
       self.root.after(self.msPerFrame, self.update)
    
       self.root.mainloop()

app = App()
```

Is a Raspberry Pi 2 B simply not strong enough for this, or what else could I do to make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't entirely answer your question as to how to improve performance using Tkinter, but I would suggest a move away from it. I started a project using GuiZero/Tkinter because it looked easy and I thought the project wasn't too complex. Intially everything was fine but pretty soon I ran into all sorts of problems including: flicker, lack of configuration options, things being displayed incorrectly or not at all. I didn't, per se, experience lag or really high CPU usage, but I had enough performance problems to make me stop using it (I also wasn't using video). In the end I switched to PyQT. I was *way* better and I wish I hadn't wasted any time on GuiZero/Tkinter. It's only suitable for the most basic of projects. I'm not suggesting PyQT is the only or best option. I've heard good things about PyGTK, but it's outside my experience.

For reference, my project was on a 4B.

Comment: I also use pyQT on one of my projects, it has some 8 different screens and hardware interaction via HDMI, USB (Touch screen and USB stick), SPI and I2C (but no video); it works flawlessly and is quick.